# How to read SAS7BDAT file from S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, readfile

I have a file.SAS7bDAT file in AWS S3 bucket. I need to read this file into a dataframe directly using boto3 client for further processing.

How can I read it in a dataframe using boto3 S3 client?
Please advise.

Comment: Since SAS isn't really being used here, I'm going to delete the SAS tag.

Comment: Google 'read file from S3 boto' and then 'read SAS7bDAT into dataframe' - breaking down problems into smaller chunks and then combinig the solutions is literally the key skill for a software engineer.